# How to build a codesandbox project to android apk?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, three.js, react-three-fiber, codesandbox

guys!

I am given a demo project at codesandbox.io, and I need to build it into android apk, how could I do that?
The project has lots of dependencies that I don't know.
I know some Javascript and DOM, and I know a little Cordova.
Is there a straight forward method to build it?

In fact, I am also ready to learn new things...
So, where should I start?
Thanks!

Here is the dependencies of the project.
`"dependencies": { "react": "18.2.0", "react-colorful": "5.6.1", "react-dom": "18.2.0", "react-icons": "4.7.1", "react-scripts": "5.0.1", "@pmndrs/branding": "0.0.8", "@react-three/drei": "9.74.8", "@react-three/fiber": "8.13.1", "@types/three": "0.152.1", "framer-motion": "10.0.1", "maath": "0.6.0", "three": "0.153.0", "valtio": "1.10.3" },`

I don't know where to start. I am expecting some kind-hearted friends to tell me how to do it.